# Tabela com barra de rolagem na horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Montei uma tabela com CSS, porém estou tendo um problema quando os relatórios são abertos em celular ou tablet. A tabela fica achatada, ou dados ficam confusos.

Tem como colocar uma barra de rolagem na horizontal, e evitar que os dados fiquem achatados?

Segue a tabela como esta:

```css
.tab_dados {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
.tab_dados a {
    color: #484848;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tab_dados th {
    background: #0091FF;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-style: italic;
} 
.tab_dados tr {
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.tab_dados tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #F7F7F7;
} 
.tab_dados tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
.tab_dados tr:hover {
    background: #F1F1F1;
}
tfoot tr td{
    border:0;
    height: 40px;
}
.tfoot{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <!-- TABELA -->
        <table class="tab_dados">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
                <th>CÓDIGO</th>
                <th>NOME</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>CIDADE</th>
                <th>ESTADO</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id='2'>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>HUGO</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='3'>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>HUGO</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='4'>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>HUGO</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='5'>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>HUGO</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
                <td>MG</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Aumentar a largura `tab_dados` para 200% nas resoluções que tu quer não te ajudaria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deveria colocar uma div como o colega @Leon Freire falou, só que você coloca em css o tamanho da div assim como também o tamanho da tabela, logo após isso, você utiliza o comando overflow em css.

```css
#caixa_tabela{
        width: 150%; /* aqui pode ser auto ou 100%*/
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .tab_dados {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .tab_dados a {
        color: #484848;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .tab_dados th {
        background: #0091FF;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-style: italic;
    } 
    .tab_dados tr {
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
    }
    .tab_dados tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #F7F7F7;
    } 
    .tab_dados tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .tab_dados tr:hover {
        background: #F1F1F1;
    }
    tfoot tr td{
        border:0;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .tfoot{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="caixa_tabela">
     <table class="tab_dados">
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 30px;"></th>
            <th>CÓDIGO</th>
            <th>NOME</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>CIDADE</th>
            <th>ESTADO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id='2'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>HUGO</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>MG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='3'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>HUGO</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>MG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='4'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>HUGO</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>MG</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id='5'>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>HUGO</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>BOA ESPERANÇA</td>
            <td>MG</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa botar uma div fora da tabela, contendo a tabela. Exemplo:

```
<div class="table">
    <table class="tab_dados">(conteúdo...)</table>
</div>
```

E por as seguintes classes:

```
div.table {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
th, td {
    min-width: 50px; /* width/largura das células à escolha */
}
```

Você precisaria de um mínimo de conhecimento em Media Queries para aplicar somente aos dispositivos desejados.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

A forma mais simples que encontrei foi colocar a tabela dentro de uma div.
No exemplo, defini a altura máxima em 600px e a largura em 100%. Ajuste como for mais adequado ao seu caso!

Boa sorte!

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 600px; width: 100%">
Sua tabela aqui
</div>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Na metodologia [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/) o componente Table trata muito bem nessa questão de responsividade para a melhor exibição tanto na web quando mobile.

Para a resoluções menores eles invertem as colunas para linhas e linhas para colunas deixando a primeira coluna fixa.

Utilizando @media query no css para especificar uma resolução para mobile você pode tratar com este mesmo casso.

Vejo um exemplo de Responsive Table com a framework [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/table.html).

Comment: Qual a utilização do `@keyframes` para essa resolução? Você quis dizer `@media`?

Comment: Isso mesmo, desculpe o engano, são os @media query.

No site go Material Design especifica bem as resoluções usadas em mobile.

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints